# Tk python app keeps freezing when using Queue

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, queue

Every time I Run my TK app it freezes, believe that it is some thing to do with the `Queue` module.

My code:

```
 import socket, os, multiprocessing, queue
import tkinter as tk

#---global variables---#

setup = ''
cleintsocket = ''
port = 0
q = queue.Queue()

#---Defs---#

def setup():
    global host, port, user
    host = setup_host_box.get()
    port = setup_port_box.get()
    user = setup_user_box.get()
    if port == '':
        port = 8545
    create_sock(host, int(port))

def connect_buffer(self, hostname, connectingport):
    connect(self, hostname, connectingport)

def connect(self, hostname, connectingport):
    '''connects to a port'''
    if hostname == '':
        hostname = 'localhost'
    self.connect((hostname, connectingport))
    resvbackgroung = multiprocessing.Process(target = resv)
    resvbackgroung.start()
    chat()

def create_sock(nhost, nport):
    '''create the cleint's socket'''
    global cleintsocket
    cleintsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connect(cleintsocket, nhost, nport)

def send(username, cleintsock):
    '''to send a message'''
    usrmsg = (username + ' - ' + chat_msg_box.get()).encode()
    cleintsock.send(usrmsg)

def resv():
    '''resive subscript, run through mutiprosses module'''
    while True:
        rmsg = cleintsocket.recv(1024).decode()
        q.put(rmsg)

def chat():
    '''loads chat page'''
    setup_host_text.pack_forget()
    setup_host_box.pack_forget()
    setup_port_text.pack_forget()
    setup_port_box.pack_forget()
    setup_user_text.pack_forget()
    setup_user_box.pack_forget()
    setup_confirm_button.pack_forget()
    chat_msg_display_text.pack()
    chat_msg_box.pack()
    chat_msg_send_button.pack()
    chat_disconnect_button.pack()
    while True:
        while not q.empty():
            msg = q.get()
            chat_msg_display_text.insert('END.END', msg)

def start():
    '''starts the setup page'''
    setup_host_text.pack()
    setup_host_box.pack()
    setup_port_text.pack()
    setup_port_box.pack()
    setup_user_text.pack()
    setup_user_box.pack()
    setup_confirm_button.pack()


def disconnect():
    '''safely closes the socket and sends a desconnect msg'''
    cleintsocket.send((user + 'has disconnected').encode())
    cleintsocket.close()
    quit()

def send_button_callback():
    '''add a buffer to allow time for 'cleintsocket' to be defined in 'create_sock()'''
    send(user, cleintsocket)

#---TK Setup---#

#--window setup--#

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Chat')
window.geometry('600x600')
window.configure(background='#ffffff')

#--connection setup page--#

setup_host_text = tk.Label(window, text = 'Host')
setup_host_box = tk.Entry(window, bg = '#ffffff')
setup_port_text = tk.Label(window, text = 'Port')
setup_port_box = tk.Entry(window, bg = '#ffffff')
setup_user_text = tk.Label(window, text = 'Username')
setup_user_box = tk.Entry(window, bg = '#ffffff')
setup_confirm_button = tk.Button(window,text = 'Connect', command = setup)

#--chat page--#

chat_msg_box = tk.Entry(window, bg='#ffffff')
chat_msg_send_button = tk.Button(window, text = 'send', command = send_button_callback)
chat_msg_display_text = tk.Text(window, width=600, height=20, insertborderwidth = 3, wrap = 'word')
chat_disconnect_button = tk.Button(window, text = 'Disconnect', command = disconnect)

#--------------#

start()
```

Thank you,

CB

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. You might want to read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if you haven't already.

Comment: @BryanOakley Actually I _have_ read the page on 'How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example' and it _doesn't_ say that you should not put code on another website, I put my code on paste bin because it is easier to format code (By the way, thank you Pythonista for the edit) into a easy format for people to read as code (rather than tabing every line of code), so before you tell someone to read the MCVE page, why don't you?

Comment: MCVE is more than just where to put the code. You've included a lot of unnecessary code. Also, you don't have to "tab every line". Copy your well-formatted code. Paste into the edit box. Select all the code. Click the button that looks like `{}`. You're done.

Comment: @BryanOakley In your first comment you complained about me putting my code on pastebin(which is not mentioned in MCVE as something you shouldn't do) and not unnecessary code, a lot of the code in my app is dependant on other functions e.g.  the `connect()` function can't run(with out it the code would not run until the `create_sock`, `create_sock` can't run until `setup()` is run, also I'm using a combination of modules I have never used together before so I don't know if/what conflicts have happen causing it to freeze. Finally Thank you for the tip in the edit box, I shall use it from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `connect` function:

You setup multiprocessing, put the function `resv` as the target for this process you have just spawned.

You then start the process, and you call `chat` directly after this which has a `while True` loop in it.

This blocks tkinter's main event thread.

Comment: Ah, so I need some form of buffer or do I need to stick the while loop in another function?

Comment: After a bit of googling I came across a thread ([link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679102/tkinter-managing-my-event-loops-alongside-my-mainloop[link]) that helped greatly turns out I could use a `self.after(1000, funtion1)` so the update_text would arrange to call its self after a set amount of time.